# Is Hydrogen rich water safe and beneficial for health

Tags: pharmacology

Is Hydrogen rich water safe and beneficial for health ? I just bought a Hydrogen water machine to try and relieve muscle inflammation.

Comment: What (the heck) is a "Hydrogen water machine"?

Comment: You should use Magnesium... 60 percent of humans are deficient in magnesium but it is used in hospitals to treat inflammation, they inject it in asthma patients who are having an acute attack into their bloodstream. it helps with cramps, stiffness, bad sleep and other stuff. nerves have massive amounts of magnesium and calcium in them.

Comment: Results

The consumption of hydrogen-rich water for 6 weeks reduced reactive oxygen metabolites in the blood and maintained blood oxidation potential. QOL scores during radiotherapy were significantly improved in patients treated with hydrogen-rich water compared to patients receiving placebo water. 

Conclusions

Daily consumption of hydrogen-rich water is a potentially novel, therapeutic strategy for improving QOL after radiation exposure. Consumption of hydrogen-rich water reduces the biological reaction to radiation-induced oxidative stress without compromising anti-tumor effects.